# android generate automatically xml file with .out

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Hello i found most of the time that one xml file is generate automatically with filename.out.xml For example my file name is example.xml But when i edit and save it then example.out.xml file is created automatically. I don't know how it is happen? Please help me to find this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when an xml file have the focus and you run your project, when you face such error follow these steps:

1. You have to deleted the xxx.out.xml
2. Clean your project  Project->Clean...->Choose your project->OK
3. Set the cursor in your *.java in /src folder,or your project global folder and Run it

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3767

To avoid it happening in the future, click on:

- Window  ->
- Preferences ->
- Run/Debug ->
- Launching ->
- Launch Operation ->
- Always Launch the previously launched application

Comment: Eclipse -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching -> Always launch the previously launched application, for newer versions of Eclipse...

Answer (score 3):

```
what i have do with this file?
```

**Delete it.**

You compiled your `example.xml` file so it create `example.out.xml`.Delete `example.out.xml` and clean your project.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're accidently trying to compile the XML-file, which leads it into creating a `example.xml.out`. When you want to run your app, make sure you're either selecting a source file in the browser to the left, or currently viewing a source file when hitting run.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i had this problem before a couple of months ago when i updated my eclipse. What i usually did is to just delete this automatically generate file and go to some class like ABC .JAVA  and then i run my project and it works fine for me. Do not run your app from any xml resources.

Answer (score 1):

in android you generally run your application with opened java file,if any .xml file is open and you try to run your application then sometime filename.out.xml file is generate automatically..

first you need to delete this out.xml file and clean your project.it works for me.i think it is help for you.